# How to detect letter of USB flash drive

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

Letter of USB flash drive is changeable and I don't know how can I detect this or  if there are more than one flash drive by using C++ or with a console line command(maybe a shortcut is exists like %APPDATA%).

How can I do it?

Comment: Assuming THERE IS more than one flash-drive, how would you know which one is "yours"?

Comment: It is not important, I must copy a file to all flash drives.

Comment: A virus writer that can't use websearch. We have truly fallen on bad times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you could use the [`GetDriveType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
UINT WINAPI GetDriveType(
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpRootPathName
);
```

> Determines whether a disk drive is a removable, fixed, CD-ROM, RAM disk, or network drive.

This will suffice if the drive type makes no difference to you. If you are interested in listing only USB flash drives, consider checking the [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

```
BOOL SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
  _In_      HDEVINFO         DeviceInfoSet,
  _In_      PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
  _In_      DWORD            Property,
  _Out_opt_ PDWORD           PropertyRegDataType,
  _Out_opt_ PBYTE            PropertyBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD            PropertyBufferSize,
  _Out_opt_ PDWORD           RequiredSize
);
```

> The SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function retrieves a specified Plug and Play device property.

Here's an example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>

...

HDEVINFO hdevinfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_USB,
                                        NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);

if (hdevinfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  return -1;

DWORD MemberIndex = 0;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA sp_devinfo_data;

ZeroMemory(&sp_devinfo_data, sizeof(sp_devinfo_data));
sp_devinfo_data.cbSize = sizeof(sp_devinfo_data);

while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hdevinfo, MemberIndex, &sp_devinfo_data))
{
  DWORD PropertyRegDataType;
  DWORD RequiredSize;
  DWORD PropertyBuffer;

  if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hdevinfo,
                                       &sp_devinfo_data,
                                       SPDRP_CAPABILITIES,
                                       &PropertyRegDataType,
                                       (PBYTE) &PropertyBuffer,
                                       sizeof(PropertyBuffer),
                                       &RequiredSize))
  {
    if (PropertyBuffer & CM_DEVCAP_REMOVABLE)
    {
      // Do something, copy your files etc
    }
  }     
  MemberIndex++;
}

SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hdevinfo);
```

Comment: Or, if you want to find flash drives in batch file, redirect
`FOR %%d IN (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO FSUTIL fsinfo drivetype %%d:` 
 to a file and parse the output.